# ReportViewer remove date time stamp in _endRequest handler

Tags: asp.net, postback, reportviewer

I added a jQuery datepicker to the report viewer control and am successfully removing the time stamp form my date parameters but for some reason when I click the 'View Report' button it looks like it is just doing a postback of the parameters each time rather than running the report. I believe it is due to how I am removing the time stamp which is in the _endRequest handler but I couldn't figure out any other way to remove the time stamp.
When I look in chrome dev tools I can see the console.log messages and it removes the time stamps and logs my messages when I first choose the date but when I hit 'view report' button it hits my console.log messages twice. Is there possibly a way to not hit the _endRequest handler when I hit the 'view report' button, maybe that would fix my issue. Also open to other ideas as well. Below is my ReportViewer html page and jQuery functions to handle the datepicker.

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptMgr" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer" Style="display: table !important; margin: 0px; overflow: auto !important;" runat="server"></rsweb:ReportViewer>

    </div>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">


        $(function () {

                $('div').add('td').attr('onclick', '');

                $('input').removeAttr('disabled');

                showDatePicker();

            // added so that datepicker reappears each time on textbox click and postback
                Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(applicationInitHandler);


                function applicationInitHandler() {
                    showDatePicker();

                            console.log("here");
                            var fromDate = document.getElementById("ReportViewer_ctl04_ctl05_txtValue").value;
                            var toDate = document.getElementById("ReportViewer_ctl04_ctl03_txtValue").value
                            console.log(toDate);
                            console.log(fromDate);
                            document.getElementById("ReportViewer_ctl04_ctl05_txtValue").value = fromDate.substring(0, 10);
                            document.getElementById("ReportViewer_ctl04_ctl03_txtValue").value = toDate.substring(0, 10);
                }



                function showDatePicker() {

                    var parameterRow = $("#ParametersRowReportViewer");
                    var innerTable = $(parameterRow).find("table").find("table");
                    var span = innerTable.find("span:contains('Date')");

                    if (span.length) {
                        var innerRow = $(span).parents('tr').eq(0);
                        var innerCell = innerRow.find('td').eq(1);
                        var textFrom = innerCell.find('input[type="text"]');

                        innerCell = innerRow.find('td').eq(4);
                        var textTo = innerCell.find('input[type="text"]');

                        $(textFrom).datepicker({
                            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
                            changeMonth: true,
                            changeYear: true,
                            numberOfYears: 1,
                            numberOfMonths: 1,
                            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                                $(textTo).datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);

                            }
                        });
                        $(textFrom).focus(function (e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            $(textFrom).datepicker("show");
                        });
                        $(textTo).datepicker({
                            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
                            changeMonth: true,
                            changeYear: true,
                            numberOfYears: 1,
                            numberOfMonths: 1,
                            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                                $(textFrom).datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
                            }
                        });
                        $(textTo).focus(function () {
                            $(textTo).datepicker("show");
                        });

                    }
                }

            });


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: On ReportViewer you must be carefully with CSS input styles. If you use any focus event on css or javascript with any input the calendar cannot be visible pressing the calendar button. Solution: use "input[type="text"]:focus {...". Try to use this event only on type="text".